# Least delay for audio processing

Tags: gpio, audio, analog-to-digital

I am working on a project that involves real-time audio processing to do noise cancellation, so basically taking input from a microphone, doing processing, and sending out the output. It heavily relies on very little delay between input and output. I bought a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2 and [this microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BOM93VK) ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coUYZ.jpg)).

From my search, I think I've narrowed it down to two things: I can either wire that microphone to a 3.5mm jack, connect it to a USB sound card, and connect it to the Pi. OR, I can get an ADC expansion sound card like the ones listed on the elinux.org page.

Which approach will give me the least delay in input and output? As far as I can tell, I'm guessing USB is slower than using the IO pins. Also, would using an Arduino instead actually be better for noise cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using USB as a relay instead of polling the audio directly on a pin would cause a higher latency.
I doubt the Arduino has enough processing power to do a software noise cancellation. I'd stick with the pi.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if using USB would be the main cause of delay. In what language you write your noise cancellation? In C++ you might make good use of the FFTW3 library, which is very fast and well written.